# Smart cast to (Int) is impossible, because <variable> is a local variable that is capture by a changing closure

Tags: android, kotlin

I know this question has been asked before, but it seems there was no resolution. I am trying to keep track of the top visible item in a `RecyclerView` by with an int variable called `topView`, which is populated by casting the view's tag (of type 'Any') to an Int:

`var topView = citationRecyclerView!!.getChildAt(0)?.tag as Int?`

I want that variable to be updated when and if the view scrolls via the onClick of a view:

```
if (recyclerView.getChildAt((topView + 6)) != null) {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(topView + 6)
            topView = (topView + 6)

        }
```

Each instance of topView in the second code block is giving me the titular error. I understand that it's to prevent the value being changed from another thread, but I only intend for it to be accessed here. How do I compare and increment this Int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kotlin compiler is also subtly pointing out "yo, what should we do if `topView` is `null`?".

If the answer is that you want to do nothing if `topView` is `null`, you can use `?.let()`:

```
topView?.let {
    val index = it + 6

    if (recyclerView.getChildAt(index) != null) {
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(index)
        topView = (index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor note in the second example, if `topView` is a property (and not a local variable) you'll need to capture it first, e.g. `val localTopView = topView` otherwise you'll still run into an issue as the property can technically change between the null check and the usage.

Comment: @kcoppock: Good point -- thanks for pointing this out! I'm cheating and electing to get rid of the second example in the interests of answer simplicity. :-)

Comment: what about if you want declare a variable outside let change it and use after. Kotlin won't allow it, thats because the language is not well designed.